# Ubuntu18.04 Fix for Syslog "rsyslogd 'action 8' suspended module (module 'builtin:omfile')" error

Tags: 18.04, permissions, apache2, syslog

Log points to permissions on `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. They were root:adm 0640. Giving Group adm write permission (change to 0644) solved the problem.

```
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="9117" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: file '/var/log/apache2/error.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Apr 30 09:57:00 openemr0 rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

Comment: This worked until the system restarted apache. The file permissions reverted and the problem returned. I have not a clue where or how to permanently fix this issue. Anyone else seen this?